# How to write a calculation using a String and convert the result to a new Double correctly?

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

I am new to java and have been asked to write a program that males three different types of calculations using three different methods. For the purpose of this question I will provide two examples of comparison. For the method that I am stuck on, the following rules must apply:

1. Must test that x("12 [ 3") returns null because [ is not a valid operator.
2. Must be written using the following parameters:

   ```
       Double x;
       /*
       * Chops up input on ' ' then decides whether to add or multiply.
       * If the string does not contain a valid format returns null.
       */

       public Double x(String x){
               return new Double(0);
       }
   ```

Here is what I have so far along with an example of another calculation which works fine:

**TestCalculator class**

```
public class TestCalculator {
        Double x;

 String string = "b";
 Double doubleObject = 1.0;
 double doublePrimitive = 2;

        public void testParsing() {

         if (multiplyx(12.0) == 60) {
            System.out.println("Multiplying Success");}
            else {
                    System.out.println("Multiplying Fail");
                    }
         if (x("12") == null) {
            System.out.println("Ovalid operator Success");}
            else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid operator Fail");
                    }
        }

        /*
        * Chops up input on ' ' then decides whether to add or multiply.
        * If the string does not contain a valid format returns null.
        */
        public Double x(String x){
                return new Double(x) + ("[ 3");
        }
        /*
        * Multiplies the parameter x by instance variable x and return the value as a Double.
        */
        public Double multiplyx(double x){
                System.out.println("== Multiplying ==");
                this.x = x;
                return new Double(x * 5);
        }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

TestCalculator call = new TestCalculator();

call.testParsing();


}
}
```

My main queries are:

- How do I make my method which uses a String as a parameter return a new Double value?
- Since anything can be put into Strings as long as they are within the quotation marks, I would I make java recognize "[" as an invalid operator?

Any help on these issues would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This: public Double x(String x) already gets string and returns double, so I can't figure out your first question. Please clarify. Regarding your second question, you'll have to specify which formats you do accept (I guess only "x*y" and "x+y", but I may be wrong).

Comment: For my first question I am getting the error "String cannot be converted to Double" so I assumed I didn't convert it properly or there's something I need to do. For the second question, I think those are the only formats that are accepted but I don't think I have formatted the code correctly to give the correct output which would be null due to "[" being an invalid operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get your errors because you try to add Double to String.

Please look at this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(x("12 + 3"));
    System.out.println(x("12 * 3"));
    System.out.println(x("12 [ 3"));
}

// Static for example purposes
public static Double x(String x){

    String[] parsed;
    if (x.contains("*")) {
        // * Is a special character in regex
        parsed = x.split("\\*");

        return Double.parseDouble(parsed[0]) * Double.parseDouble(parsed[1]);
    }
    else if (x.contains("+")) {
        // + is again a special character in regex
        parsed = x.split("\\+");

        return Double.parseDouble(parsed[0]) + Double.parseDouble(parsed[1]);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `x` takes a `String` and returns a `Double`. Your task is to convert the string to a value by interpreting the string as an expression. Without supplying the answer here are some hints:

1. Split the string up (`String.split`)
2. Convert the arguments to values (`Double.parseDouble`)
3. Use a `switch` statement on the operator to determine what to return
4. As the `default` of the switch, return a `null`

That should give you enough to get you started